# Do certain SQL JOINS make your ASP.NET Application incredibly slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, join

I am talking about certain SQL JOIN (not all) which make your application crawling. I once produced this in my code and I thought it was really a bug by Microsoft. The problem was that the query performed just fine in SQL Management Studio but in your application it made everything stop for 10+ seconds unless the query completes. I think this is really a bug.

An example of it is [here in the Microsoft bugs/feedback site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback). It take incredible 8 seconds just to go from one page to another. Can't they optimize this for god sake, if they could? This I believe is a manifestation of that bug.

Have anyone come across it and can someone identify it? I am trying to troubleshoot my own slow queries but want to clarify this first.

Comment: Are you using the SQL directly or an ORM e.g. EF? Is it exactly the same query in your code on the same data? Are you returning large amounts of data in the query? Can you profile it and see what it's doing for those 10 seconds? I think we'd need lots more information to be of any help.

Comment: There is nothing inherently slow about using JOINs.  The question is whether the database is correctly optimised (normalisation, indexing, etc) and if the query is particularly complex.  If you have an under-performing query, it would be worth supplying the query, the schema and example data.

Comment: Right there is nothing wrong with the Join. I am not saying JOIN are slow. What I am saying is there are particular JOINS ( a little more complex) that makes your ASP.NET Application crawl. I once produced it but can't produce it now. I have given MSFT link to get taste of it. How can it be so slow?

Comment: That is only 80,000 records? You think pulling 80k records in SSMS will take 8 seconds even if you are just getting to the next page. I dont think so :)

Comment: I have not found that particular query yet which makes your application really slow but Microsoft example in the question itself is a proof. My ASP.NET is really slow, even logins can take 10 seconds. But that is a different problem from the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

you need to read and understand this: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

here is the table of contents:

- **Introduction**
  Presumptions
- **How SQL Server Compiles a Stored Procedure**
  What is a Stored Procedure?
  How SQL Server Generates the Query Plan
  Putting the Query Plan into the Cache
  Different Plans for Different Settings
  The Default Settings
  The Effects of Statement Recompile
  The Story So Far
- **It's Not Always Parameter Sniffing...**
  Replacing Variables and Parameters
  Blocking
  Indexed Views and Indexed Computed Columns
  An Issue with Linked Servers
- **Getting Information to Solve Parameter Sniffing Problems**
  Getting the Necessary Facts
  Which is the Slow Statement?
  Getting the Query Plans and Parameters with Management Studio
  Getting the Query Plans and Parameters Directly from the Plan Cache
  Getting Query Plans and Parameters from a Trace
  Getting Table and Index Definitions
  Finding Information About Statistics
- **Examples of How to Fix Parameter-Sniffing Issues**
  A Non-Solution
  Best Index Depends on Input
  Dynamic Search Conditions
  Reviewing Indexing
  The Case of the Application Cache
  Fixing Bad SQL
- **How SQL Server Compiles Dynamic SQL**
  What Is Dynamic SQL?
  Generating the Plan for Dynamic SQL
  Dynamic SQL and the Plan Cache
  Running Application Queries in SSMS
  Addressing Parameter-sniffing Problems in Dynamic SQL
  Plan Guides
- **Further Reading**
- **Revisions**

Answer (score 2):

Data size is one variable that will drastically change performance in management studio vs. production.

Another variable is data being returned from the query - if you're on sql management studio locally vs. pulling remotely and also the C# code itself - what is it doing with that data.

Also, Sql Server generates query plans based off of statistics.  The query plan decides which indexes to use.  You should capture the query plan.  If that's an issue, you can also provide query plan hints to use certain indexes.

You need to profile your C# code and analyze your query plans.  How to read and optimize query plans is beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: All my application and data is on the same computer. I unfortunately do not have profiler. Ok I will take your advice, but how about giving an advice to Microsoft themselves? Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

I've never noticed a query that performs well in management studio failing to perform when I run it live from my application. Some SQL joins are obviously slower than others of course but you shouldnt see a 1second query taking 20seconds to execute or anything like that.

One thing to remember though is that an ASP webpage will run slightly slower than the exec time of the stored procedure anyway. When you run the query in management studio you are just running the query however when you request a page from the server the connection has to be opened to the database, the query has to be executed then the page has to render with the data retrieved from the query so this adds overhead the query execution time you may be noticing.

Do you have a current example of this with your own code we could look at?

I just checked out that MS site, the response time really is terrible I cant believe that someone would actually let something like that go live.

Comment: That's what I am talking about. If Microsoft can't fix their, do you think it is fixable. I produced my query when building a new feature and I noticed at the time this is the same bug as in Microsft. I since then changed the logic and that particular query is OK. But there is certain type of Query that does make your application crawl. I want to identify that. So I can probably produce that query if I look into it and I am lucky it is still there somewhere.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I dont think this is an issue of MS not being able to fix it, I think its just an issue of poor design on that page, there are 850+ pages of data, I would guess they are either loading too much data at once or something like that. Either way I would say that is bad code not a bug with SQL

Comment: @purplegoldish, having worked at Microsoft, I can tell you there are very talented ppl who work there. They are not dumb. They will fix anything they can (unless the project manager dont want to). If they can't fix it, they will leave it as it and wont touch it which is the case here. Probably no one filed a bug on this one and they don't seem to care to spend more time on it to fix it.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I never said that people who work at Microsoft are not talented, but the performance on that page to display the data it does is terrible. I have seen examples of similar things done with a LOT faster performance. If a project manager decides not to fix it then thats their choice but it doesnt make the page well designed. If it takes longer to load a page than it does to read it then there is a flaw somewhere. If this were a flaw with SQL it would pop up a lot more often than just a few sites

Comment: @Purplegoldsih, oh try moving from page1 to page2 and see what happen. Try changing the category (the orange button). In my case the page louds pretty much fast, it is the query that the gridview is waiting on. In my case, every single click take about 8 second to refresh data. This is not HTML issue, but SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Check the default settings in your program and in SSMS. For example, if you run SET ARITHABORT OFF in SSMS, you might find that it now runs as slow as when running your program.

What I found once was that SET ARITHABORT OFF in SSMS caused the stored proc to be recompiled and/or different statistics to be used. And suddenly both SSMS and my program were reporting roughly the same execution time.

To check this, look at the execution plans for each run, specifically the syscacheobjects table. They will probably be different.

Finally, you can try cleaning out procedure cache and memory buffers using SSMS:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Doing so before you test your query prevents usage of cached execution plans and previous results cache.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the query and the join(s). Joins by themselves, no matter what type, will not impact performance to the extent you're referring to.

Comment: I have provided Microsoft site as an example. Clearly SSMS will never tak 8 seconds to query 80,000 records but everyone seems to miss that point.

Comment: Have you considered that it might not be the query that's causing the lag, but rather rendering or manipulation of the result set?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am saying in the first place. In my view that is a bug if rendering of a particular query takes 10 seconds.

Comment: It may not be a problem with the query at all though. It may not even be a bug, in the traditional sense. It could just be that the page is not as efficient as it could be.